# ¿Qué debo colocar en el action para que inserte los datos en este formulario PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy realizando un plugin para wordpress, con PHP. He creado la siguiente clase:

```
if (!class_exists('UsersConfig')) {
    class UsersConfig
    {
        public static function init()
        {

            add_action('admin_menu', 'UsersConfig::createAdminMenu');

            add_action('admin_post_set_users',  'UsersConfig::set_users_post');
        }

       
        public static function createAdminMenu()
        {
            add_menu_page(
                'Users', //page_title
                'Config', //menu_title
                'administrator', //capability:'edit_posts'
                'usuarios', //menu slug
                'UsersConfig::users_views', //page_callback_function
                'dashicons-media-spreadsheet', //icon_url 
                6 //position 
            );

            add_submenu_page(
                "",
                "Set",
                "Set",
                "administrator",
                "users_set",
                "UsersConfig::users_set_view"
            );
        }

        /**
         * Mostrar la tabla con los usuarios
         */
        public static function users_views()
        {
            require(__DIR__ . "/views/users.php");
        
        }


        /**
         * Editar el usuario
         *
         */
        public static function users_set_view()
        {
            require(__DIR__ . "/views/setUsers.php");
        }

        /**
         * Editar usuario (POST)
         */
        public static function set_users_post()
        {
            global $wpdb;

            if ($_POST["id"] == 0) {
               
                //Comprobar los datos...
                $datos = [];

                //Comprobar nombre
                if (array_key_exists("userName", $_POST) && !empty($_POST["userName"])) {
                    $datos["userName"] = $_POST["userName"];
                }
                if (array_key_exists("userHome", $_POST) && !empty($_POST["userHome"])) {
                    $datos["userHome"] = $_POST["userHome"];
                }
                if (array_key_exists("userSurname", $_POST) && !empty($_POST["userSurname"])) {
                    $datos["userSurname"] = $_POST["userSurname"];
                }
                if (array_key_exists("dateOfBirth", $_POST) && !empty($_POST["dateOfBirth"])) {
                    $datos["dateOfBirth"] = $_POST["dateOfBirth"];
                }


                    //Meter códigos en db.
                  
                        $nombre = $_POST['userName'];
                        $zona_residencia = $_POST['userHome'];
                        $apellido = $_POST['userSurname'];
                        $fecha_nacimiento = $_POST['dateOfBirth'];

                       
                        $datos_insertar_users = [
                            "Id" => null,
                            "userName" => $nombre,
                            "userHome" => $zona_residencia,
                            "userSurname" => $apellido,
                            "dateOfBirth" => $fecha_nacimiento

                        ];

                        $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix . "users_data", $datos_insertar_users);
                        
        }
```

Esto es la clase. El problema es que a la hora de intentar insertar un nuevo usuario, no sé que poner en el action del formulario. El método estático `users_set_view nos lleva al siguiente formulario, que envía los datos por el método post. En el init ya se ve, y es:

```
<?php
$userId = array_key_exists("id",$_GET) ? $_GET["id"] : 0;

$user= null;

if ($userId > 0){
    global $wpdb;
    $user= $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users_data WHERE Id='".$userId."'");
}
?>

<div class="page-header">
    <?php
    if ($userId > 0){
        echo "<h3>Editar Usuarios</h3>";
    }else{
        echo "<h3>Añadir Usuarios</h3>";
    }
    ?>
   
    <form method="post" **action=""** enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$userId?>"/>

        <fieldset>
            <label for="userName"><strong>Nombre Usuario</strong></label>
            <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" required="true" style="width:100%" 
            value="<?= $user != null ? $user->userName : ''?>"/>
        </fieldset>
        
        ..........................................
        <fieldset>
            <button name="btnAdd" id="btnAdd" class='page title-action' style=
            "float:right;">Añadir/Editar nuevo usuario</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Mi problema es ¿que pongo en el action para que los datos se envíen al método set_users_post()? He probado con llamadas al método, a la clase... y nada me ha funcionado. Gracias de antemano y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad, se trataba de algo tan sencillo como:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnAdd'])){
//llamar a la función estática creada

UsersConfig::set_users_post():

}
```

Saludos y gracias por vuestro interés.